# How to Position Fixed with LOTS elements inside

Tags: css, css-position

I'm working on a simple page but got into a trouble with fixed position.  Wonder if anyone has the time to give me a hand.

It will be too much to copy and paste all the codes here but I will paste a link

http://et4891.com/lecture/protosite.shtml

for the header with the nav I want both being fixed which means when I'm scrolling down the page the whole header with nav will always be there.  But no matter how I do it things just keep on messed up.  The nav is with css dropdown and floating.

Anyone able to give me a hand? I want to fix the position only with css not jquery though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw header and nav into a div. Give that div `position: fixed;`. Make sure you increase `margin-top` for `proto-main-content` as this section is no longer affected by the header and nav's position.